# offline usage of a wwb application

Tags: mobile, offline

I have a requirement to build a simple page which caches salesforce data  when i go offline, and auto sync when i come online for moblie site. Can we do it with simple html 5 and javascript? what sort of javascript we will use? i dont want to use hybid or native. is there any solution regarding this. i have build a page wgich can save data offline usiing offline.js but can not sync it back with salesforce.
Also can we use salesforce logged in session offline?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I once did that using the ForceTK javascript library and wrote the sync mechanism myself. But that was only for a very small and specific set of data.

You might want to look at the SmartSync data framework which comes with the Salesforce Mobile SDK. 

And never forget: There's no really secure offline storage mechanism for HTML5 websites I know off.

You write that you can not sync it back to Salesforce. What exactly is your problem? Do you have any code which doesn't work? Can you share it including an error message?

Comment: Shailesh that's a very broad combination of questions, rather unsuited for the stackexchange format (specific questions which can be answered correct and are not discussions). Could you maybe edit your question to specify to a single issue?